# Why does this PUSH instruction cause a UNDEFINED_INSTRUCTION exception at my ARM processor?

Tags: exception, assembly, arm

I am working with a Cortex-A9 and my program crashes because of an UNDEFINED_INSTRUCTION exception. The assembly line that causes this exception is according to my debugger's trace:

Trace #9999 : S:0x022D9A7C E92D4800 ARM PUSH     {r11,lr}

Exception: UNDEFINED_INSTRUCTION (9)

I program in C and don't write assembly or binary and I am using gcc. Is this really the instruction that causes the exception, i.e. is the encoding of this PUSH instruction wrong and hence a compiler/assembler bug? Or is the encoding correct and something strange is going on? Scrolling back in the trace I found another PUSH instruction, that does not cause errors and looks like this:

Trace #9966 : S:0x022A65FC E52DB004 ARM PUSH     {r11}

And of course there are a lot of other PUSH instruction too. But I did not find any other that tries to push specifically R11 and LR, so I can't compare.

I can't answer my own question, so I edit it:

Sorry guys, I don't exactly know what happend. I tried it several times and got the same error again and again. Then I turned the device off, went away and tried it again later and know it works fine... 
Maybe the memory was corrupted somehow due to overheating or something? I don't know. Thanks for your answers anyway. 
I use gcc 4.7.2 btw.

Comment: Need more information, provide more lines of disassembly around the instruction in question.  Since you are using a debugger provide the stack pointer around/before the instruction in question.

Comment: Can you provide the C code that this instruction was "generated" from? If you're using IAR, then you can view both (C code and assembly code) through the 'View' menu / 'Disassembly' option.

Comment: the encoding is good, it is not the encoding. e92d4800  push {fp, lr} e52db004  push {fp}.  How old of a compiler are you using that would generate a push {r11} like that, ARM compilers now only push and pop even numbers of registers

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something is corrupting the SP register. Load/store multiple (of which PUSH is one alias) to unaligned addresses are undefined in the architecture, so if SP gets overwritten with something that's not a multiple of 4, then a subsequent push/pop will throw an undef exception.

Now, if you're on ARM Linux, there is (usually) a [kernel trap for unaligned accesses](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/mem_alignment) left over from the bad old days which if enabled will attempt to fix up most unaligned load/store multiple instructions (despite them being architecturally invalid). However if the address is invalid (as is likely in the case of SP being overwritten with nonsense) it will give up and leave the undef handler to do its thing.

In the (highly unlikely) case that the compiler has somehow generated bad code that is fix-uppable most of the time,

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo/alignment
```

would show some non-zero fixup counts, but as I say, it's most likely corruption - a previous function has smashed the stack in such a way that an invalid SP is loaded on return, that then shows up at the next stack operation. Best double-check your pointer and array accesses.